# Finding an item in a two-dimensional list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to program the game 'Snake' in Python, but i can't find out if an item like next, containing x and y variables, is inside the two-dimensional list snake.
I wrote this code to demonstrate my problem:

```py
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
import time

#Variables
dead = False
##List for snake consiting of 4 white pixels
snake = [[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4]] 
last = snake[-1]
next = list(last)   

###FUNCTIONS

def check():
  if next in snake:
    dead = True


##MAIN      
sense.clear()
check()

while dead == True:
    sense.show_message("dead")


while dead == False:
    sense.show_message("alive")
```

The output is always "alive", although  next is in snake.
I'm using the Sense HAT module emulator on:
https://trinket.io/sense-hat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define next as `[1,4]` not `[[1,4]]` to be able to test if next is in snake